# paypal rest api payment call returning 401 using php

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to add paypal to my site.  I have been following the instructions at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/, but it is not working.  I have sent the request for an access token successfully and gotten a response.  The information in the response is stored in an object called $accessToken.  The problem lies when I try to make the API call in step 3 from the site listed above.  I get a 401 error sent back from the request.  I'm pretty sure the $url that the request is sent to as a function parameter is correct.  It is https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment. I have been going all over the internet for help for the past week and a half, and I haven't made any progress whatsoever.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
function MakePaymentAPICall($accessToken, $sale, $url, $url_success, $url_cancel){

// Create cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// Set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$tokenType = $accessToken->GetTokenType();
$token = $accessToken->GetAccessToken();
$auth = "Authorization:" . $tokenType . " " . $token;
$saleTotal = $sale->GetTotal();

$header = array(
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
'Authorization' => $tokenType . ' ' . $token
);


$dataArray = array(
    'intent' => 'sale',
    'redirect_urls' => array(
            'return_url' => $url_success,
            'cancel_url' => $url_cancel
        ),
    'payer' => array(
            'payment_method' => 'paypal'
        ),
    'transactions' => array(
            'amount' => array(
                    'total' => $saleTotal,
                    'currency' => 'USD'
                ),
            'description' => 'Test payment.'
        )
);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, http_build_query($header));


// set data to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($dataArray));


curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


// Execute curl command
$output = curl_exec($ch);


// Get info about request
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


// Close cURL resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
```

} // MakePaymentAPICall function

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

@Jason247

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

I think that **CURLOPT_HEADER** requires an int or bool, either 1 or TRUE to send headers.

I do believe **CURLOP_HTTPHEADER** is what you want, you can pass an array directly to it without encoding to a query string.

e.g.

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
```

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error generally indicates that the access token is either invalid or expired:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest-payments-error-handling/

Are you including "Bearer" in the Authorization header? Example:

`Authorization:Bearer EMxItHE7Zl4cMdkvMg-f7c63GQgYZU8FjyPWKQlpsqQP`

Comment: Yes, in the header array I have 'Authorization' => $tokenType . ' ' . $token.  The $tokenType contains "Bearer" and the $token contains the access token. Thanks!

Comment: I am still stuck on this problem.  Can anyone help?